# Why if $f_{\infty} \geq f(R_n)$, then no subsequence of $P_k$ can collapse to a segment?

Tags: geometric-topology, polygons

In the article [The sound of Symmetry](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.122.9.815?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) in **Proposition $6$**, there is a problem that bothers me and I cannot solve. Could anyone is able to explain to me why if $f_{\infty} \geq f(R_n)$, then no subsequence of $P_k$ can collapse to a segment?

**Definitions :**

1. $f$ is the isoperimetric quotient $f(\Omega) = \frac{|\Omega|}{|\partial \Omega|}$.
2. $R_n$ is a regular $n$-gon.
3. $f_{\infty}$ is the limit of $f(P_k)$ as $k \to \infty$ for a sequence of convex $n$-gons $\{P_k\}$

Comment: What is $f_\infty$?

Comment: In the attached document, since $f$ is bounded above by the set of all convex $n$-gons in the plane modulo equivalence under rigid motions, noted $\mathcal{M}_n$, by $f(\mathbb{D})$, the supremum of $f$ on $\mathcal{M}_n$, denoted by $f_{\infty}$, is the limit of $f(P_k)$ as $k \to \infty$ for a sequence of convex $n$-gons $\{P_k\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rowlett is hosting a preprint of the paper [here](http://www.math.chalmers.se/math/grundutb), where it is not behind a paywall.

**Setup**: Notice that $f$ is positive and bounded on $\mathfrak{M}_n$. We let $f_\infty = \sup f(\mathfrak{M}_n) \in [0,f(\mathbb{D})]$, which exists because $f$ is bounded above by $f(\mathbb{D})$. As $f_\infty$ is the supremum of the image of $f$, there exists a sequence $P_k\in \mathfrak{M}_n$ such that $f(P_k)\to f_\infty$.

**Crucial observation** The fact that $\lim_{k\to\infty} f(P_k) = f_\infty > 0$ precludes a subsequence of the $P_k$ from degenerating to a line segment, as that subsequence $P_{k_i}$ would have $f(P_{k_i})\to_{i\to\infty} 0$. (This is key in the base case $n=3$, as it forces the $P_k$ to converge to $R_3$, the equilateral triangle.)

Comment: There's just a settle detail that bothers me : Why if a subsequence of $P_k$ degenerating to a line segment implies that this subsequence converge to $0$. I'd appreciate if you could just insert some more details. :)

Comment: @DavidLabrecque I'll double-check the link later. To your question, it is because $f(\mbox{line segment}) = 0$. :)

Comment: If you may also add a proof or a result why "As $f_{\infty}$ is the supremum of the image of $f$, there exists a sequence $P_k\in \mathfrak{M}_n$ such that $f(P_k)\to f_\infty$."

Comment: @DavidLabrecque It's not hard; I think I will leave it as an exercise for you.

Comment: Could you give just a hint maybe?

Comment: @DavidLabrecque If $R\subset \mathbb{R}$ is bounded, then there exists some $r = \sup R$. As a supremum, why must there exist a sequence $r_k\in R$ such that $r_k\to r$? Now if $R$ is the image of some function ...

Comment: In fact, as $f$ is invariant under scaling, I think we could fix the perimeter in such a way $|\partial P| = |\partial R_3|$. As regular $n$-gon has greater area than all other $n$-gons with the same perimeter, then $f(P) = f(R_3)$ hold if and only if $|P|=|R_3|$ if and only if $P = R_3$. Am I right?

Comment: @DavidLabrecque I think you should write these musings up as a separate question.